# SNOWFLAKE QUESTION: Using the RANK () Windows Function in SQL- where the column you want to order by isn't ordinal

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So, here's a sample of my data:

[image: Sample Data]

Essentially, I want to rank the vehicles latitude coordinates (to see where the most common places to park are). However, when I try and use the rank() windows function:

RANK () OVER (
PARTITION BY Vehicle_ID
ORDER BY Latitude DESC
) RANKINGS

However, this assumes the latitude column is ordinal and thus, ranks them according to that (placing the highest latitude as #1).

I'm guessing I need to add a frequency column first (which I've not been able to to). Once I've got that, would I need to partition by both the latitude AND vehicle ID columns.

The desired output would be to have rankings alongside latitude, group by vehicle ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additional count could be addedd:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Vehicle_Id, Latitude) AS cnt
  FROM tab
)
SELECT *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Vehicle_ID ORDER BY cnt DESC) AS RANKINGS
FROM cte;
```